# Why is Jitted Numba function slower than original function?

Tags: python, numpy, performance, numba

I've written a function to create uniformly spaced points on a disk and since it's run quite often and on relatively large array I figured the application of `numba` would increase the speed significantly. However, upon running a quick test I've found that the `numba` function is more than twice as slow.

Is there a way to figure out what is slowing down the `numba` function?

Here's the function:

```py
@njit(cache=True)
def generate_points_turbo(centre_point, radius, num_rings, x_axis=np.array([-1, 0, 0]), y_axis=np.array([0, 1, 0])):
    """
    Generate uniformly spaced points inside a circle
    Based on algorithm from:
    http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/2015/07/23/generating-equidistant-points-on-unit-disk/
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    centre_point : np.ndarray (1, 3)
    radius : float/int
    num_rings : int
    x_axis : np.ndarray
    y_axis : np.ndarray

    Returns
    -------
    points : np.ndarray (n, 3)

    """
    if num_rings > 0:
        delta_R = 1 / num_rings
        ring_radii = np.linspace(delta_R, 1, int(num_rings)) * radius
        k = np.arange(num_rings) + 1
        points_per_ring = np.rint(np.pi / np.arcsin(1 / (2*k))).astype(np.int32)
        num_points = points_per_ring.sum() + 1
        ring_indices = np.zeros(int(num_rings)+1)
        ring_indices[1:] = points_per_ring.cumsum()
        ring_indices += 1
        points = np.zeros((num_points, 3))

        points[0, :] = centre_point

        for indx in range(len(ring_radii)):
            theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, points_per_ring[indx]+1)
            points[ring_indices[indx]:ring_indices[indx+1], :] = ((ring_radii[indx] * np.cos(theta[1:]) * x_axis[:, None]).T
                     + (ring_radii[indx] * np.sin(theta[1:]) * y_axis[:, None]).T)
        return points + centre_point
```

And it's called like this:

```py
centre_point = np.array([0,0,0])
radius = 1
num_rings = 15

generate_points_turbo(centre_point, radius, num_rings )
```

Would be great if someone knows why the function is slower when `numba` compiled or how to go about finding out what the bottleneck for the `numba` function is.

#### Update: Possible computer specific size dependence

It seems the `numba` function is working, but the cross-over between where it's faster and slower maybe be hardware specific.

```py
%timeit generate_points(centre_point, 1, 2)
99.5 µs ± 932 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
%timeit generate_points_turbo(centre_point, 1, 2)
213 µs ± 8.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

%timeit generate_points(centre_point, 1, 20)
647 µs ± 11.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
%timeit generate_points_turbo(centre_point, 1, 20)
314 µs ± 8.74 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

%timeit generate_points(centre_point, 1, 200)
11.9 ms ± 375 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit generate_points_turbo(centre_point, 1, 200)
7.9 ms ± 243 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

After about 12-15 rings the `numba` function (*_turbo) starts to become a similar speed or faster on my machine, but the performance gains at larger size are smaller than expected. But seems like it is actually working, just that some part of the function is heavily size dependent.

Comment: Did you measure the time taken by the function, or the function + its compilation?

Comment: @Guimoute I used timeit after running the function once to compile it

Comment: Apart from adding the dtype  to line `ring_indices = np.zeros(int(num_rings) + 1, dtype=np.int32)` (otherwise I got an error), the numba version is ~2x faster on my computer

Comment: You might have better results by cleaning your algorithm a bit too. There are too many slices, new axes, transpositions, etc. Probably none of that is useful. The reference algorithm in Matlab is much simpler than yours in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got rid of all your transpositions / newaxis / 3D stuff that you were not using and got a x20 boost compared to your original solution. I replaced a `range` with a `prange` too for good measure, as you don't care in which order your points are calculated.

```py
# Imports.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numba import njit, prange
import numpy as np

# "Turbo" function.
@njit(cache=True)
def generate_points_turbo(centre_point, radius, num_rings):
    """
    Generate uniformly spaced points inside a circle
    Based on algorithm from:
    http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/2015/07/23/generating-equidistant-points-on-unit-disk/

    Parameters
    ----------
    centre_point : np.ndarray (2,)
    radius : float/int
    num_rings : int
    x_axis : np.ndarray
    y_axis : np.ndarray

    Returns
    -------
    points : np.ndarray (n, 2)

    """
    if not num_rings > 0:
        return

    delta_R = 1 / num_rings
    ring_radii = np.linspace(delta_R, 1, num_rings) # Use a unit circle that we will scale only at the end.
    k = np.arange(num_rings) + 1
    points_per_ring = np.rint(np.pi / np.arcsin(1 / (2*k))).astype(np.int32)
    num_points = points_per_ring.sum() + 1

    points = np.zeros((num_points, 2))
    n = 1 # n == 0 is the central point by design.

    for ring_number in prange(len(ring_radii)):
        r = ring_radii[ring_number] # The local radius between 1/num_rings and 1.
        points_on_this_ring = points_per_ring[ring_number]
        theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, points_on_this_ring)
        points[n: n+points_on_this_ring, 0] = r * np.cos(theta)
        points[n: n+points_on_this_ring, 1] = r * np.sin(theta)
        n += points_on_this_ring

    return points * radius + centre_point



# Test that the result is accurate.
if __name__ == "__main__":

    centre_point = np.array([0, 0])
    radius = 3.14159
    num_rings = 10

    p = generate_points_turbo(centre_point, radius, num_rings)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.set_aspect(1)
    ax.scatter(*p.T)
    fig.show()
```

[image]

```
 # Test time taken.
 >>> from timeit import timeit
 >>> from initial_code import generate_points_turbo as generate_points_turbo_stackoverflow

 >>> %timeit generate_points_turbo(centre_point, radius, num_rings)
 >>> 13.5 µs ± 21.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
 >>> %timeit generate_points_turbo_stackoverflow(np.array([0, 0, 0]), radius, num_rings)
 >>> 261 µs ± 1.03 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: It's exactly what I had in mind to support a circle in 3D space, just rotate the result of the current function and add `[0 0 z]` to give the center of the circle a third dimension.

Comment: Something along the lines of `points_3d = points[:, np.newaxis]`, `points_3d = rotate(points, theta, phi)`, `points_3d += centre_point` (a 3D positiion, remove references to `centre_point` from `generate_points` in that case).